# View query of shared dataset that is joined with another dataset

Tags: amazon-quicksight

Typically, when I click "Edit dataset" I can view the sql query used to create the dataset. When I click "Edit dataset" on a dataset that is joined with another dataset, I cannot view the query or the schema that shows the join. These are shared datasets so I suspect that it's an issue with permissions but using the quicksight cli wasn't helpful because I got this error when I try to describe the dataset

```
An error occurred (InvalidParameterValueException) when calling the DescribeDataSet operation: The data set type is not supported through API yet
```

Has anyone experienced something similar?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the issue was that the datasets were being manually joined against a csv file that was uploaded by another account. Manually uploaded files don't have an associated data source, so they can't be viewed by other accounts. I transferred ownership from the account that uploaded the csv to myself and now I'm able to view the datasets.